# Pandas , Sum Values of two columns from 2 DFs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two data-frames as shown below (sample data) :

df1:

```
Key1    Val1    Val2    Val3
A       2       1       3
B       2       2       2
C       3       3       4
D       4       4       2
E       5       6       5
```

df2:

```
Key1    Seasionality
A       1.2
B       -1
C       1
D       1.2
E       1.5
```

How can we add `Seasonality` to `df1 (val1, val2 , val3) where df1.key1 = df2.key1`.

Desired Output:

```
Key1    Val1    Val2    Vale
A       3.2     2.2     4.2
B       1       1       1
C       4       4       5
D       5.2     5.2     3.2
E       6.5     7.5     6.5
```

Previously i had similar requirement where i need to add columns from two different df with same keys but they had similar column names, so i was able to use :

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

But can not think of a solution to above problem.

Comment: try pandas.DataFrame.join instead...?

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

Comment: I dont need to add column seasonality to Df1 but add values of Seasionality  to all three value columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to align the keys temporarily:

```
df1.set_index('Key1', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('Key1', inplace=True)
df1 = df1.add(df2['Seasionality'], axis=0)
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: I think i was not clear enough in my question , I have updated it with  Desired output above

Comment: Thanks it worked , was simple indeed if you know what to do, cheers.

Comment: `cols = ['Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3']; df1[cols] = df1[cols].add(df2['Seasionality'], axis=0)` would do too.

Comment: @Zero Only if the rows in both dataframes are sorted by Key1.